# Requisição HTTP POST com x-www-form-urlencoded no Agular 6

Tags: angular, http, post

Preciso fazer uma requisição POST HTTP com x-www-form-urelcoded no angular 6.

Tentei algo como:

```
  pesquisaEmail(email): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    this.token = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');

    return this._http.post<any>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT_EMAIL,
      {email: email,
      token_jc: this.token},
      { headers: headers, observe: 'response' })
        .pipe(
          map((response) => ({data: response.body, status: response.status}))
      )}

}
```

@Edit
Também tentei:

```
pesquisaEmail(email): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    this.token = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
    let body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.set('email', this.token);
    body.set('token_jc', email);

    return this._http.post<any>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT_EMAIL,
      body,
      { headers: headers, observe: 'response' })
        .pipe(
          map((response) => ({data: response.body, status: response.status}))
      )}

}
```

mas sem sucesso

Recebo um bad request error.
Alguém sabe como posso fazer esse tipo de requisição?

Comment: aqui tem um exemplo:https://gist.github.com/dherges/442d3a7bc65e3e46d8dead728e4d8be8

Comment: Qual é o erro exatamente?

Comment: Eu tentei fazer o http post pelo postman e recebo os dados que preciso, mas me retorna 400 Bad Request. É possível eu capturar esses dados mesmo tendo um bad request ou o problema é no backend?

Comment: Eu acho que o problema é no backend!

Comment: Pelo postman eu recebo como retorno 400 mas ao mesmo tempo retorna os dados que preciso. Ai to sem saber o que fazer.

Comment: Então tem um tela de erros pra você adicionar na sua pergunta?